# Scaling property of Brownian motions and stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

This is a proof verification. 
I would be grateful if you could point out any problems.

Let $W=\{W_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a standard two dimensional Brownian motion starting at the origin. For $r>0$ and $R>0$, we define $\sigma_{r}=\inf \{t>0 \mid B_t \in \{r\} \times \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\tau_R=\inf \{t>0 \mid B_t \notin B(R)\}$, where $B(R)$ denotes the ball centered at the origin with radius $R$. Please notice that $\sigma_{r}$ is a first hitting time of a **one**-dimensional Brownian motion.

Let us fix $r>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then, we find that 
\begin{align*}
&P(\tau_{nr^{1/2}} \le \sigma_{r})=P(r^{-1} \tau_{nr^{1/2}} \le r^{-1} \sigma_r)\\
&=P(\tau_{n} \le r^{-1} \sigma_r)=P(\tau_n \le \sigma_{r^{1/2}}).
\end{align*}
In the above display, we used the scaling property of Brownian motion, which implies that $r^{-1} \tau_{nr^{1/2}}=\tau_{n}$ and $r^{-1} \sigma_r=\sigma_{r^{1/2}}$ in the sense of distribution. Is my argument correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. If you want to make it even more bullet proof, maybe formalize why the saying property of one dimensional Brownian motion implies scaling of $\tau$